# Deploying a Spring Boot and Angular application on XAMPP on a different server

Tags: angular, spring-boot, apache, xampp, remote-server

I've developed a Java web application (using Spring Boot and Angular). Initially, I deployed and tested it on XAMPP on my localhost, and it worked fine. Subsequently, I deployed it on a remote server's XAMPP, where testing via the server's browser was successful. However, when attempting to test it from my own computer's browser, the backend functionality failed to respond, although the frontend (specifically the login page) displayed properly. Upon attempting to log in [pic of login page after connecxion clic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5nhG.png), I encountered the following error in the browser console after 21seconde:

```
POST http://sreublc07:8080/capitalisationbackv2/api/auth/signin net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

In this error message:

- "sreublc07" refers to the server's name.
- "capitalisationbackv2" is the name of the backend WAR file.

[pic of the browser consol after login try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGuKu.png)
[pic of the browser network after login try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3awDz.png)
[pic of the browser network after login try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5UZg.png)
[pic of the browser network after login try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBHt9.png)

It's worth mentioning that the application was previously functional on an older server.

I've tried to change the Paths of connection in backend and frontend whithoud any result.